# How to know emacs true mode names?

Tags: emacs

Sometimes I copy configuration options from the Internet to my `.emacs`. Sometimes they don't work.

```
(add-hook 'laTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

doesn't work:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)
```

(notice the uppercase in Latex). But,

```
(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook 'flyspell-buffer)
```

is correct. Although Emacs shows "Fly" in the lower bar and also <kbd>M-:</kbd> `major-mode` shows latex-mode and not Latex-mode.

How do I know how to write emacs modes name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're actually more interested in the names of modes' *hook variables* than in the modes themselves.

You have several options. I will suggest some, based around discovering `flyspell-mode-hook`:

- `M-x apropos-variable RET flyspell RET`, then search the results buffer for `hook`
- `C-h v flyspell-`, then tab-complete

  - Any time you are in the minibuffer tab-completion is a good thing to try
- `M-x find-function flyspell-mode RET` will open up the source code for `flyspell`, you can then search for `hook`
- If you have configured your Emacs to provide completion for Emacs Lisp, you can simply type

  ```
  (add-hook 'flyspell-
  ```

  into your `.emacs` buffer and let Emacs suggest valid completion
- Tools like [Helm](http://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) and [`ido`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) can simplify the process of finding things

Using the `find-function` technique with `latex-mode` (which I tab-completed), I discovered that my version of Emacs calls its LaTeX mode function `latex-mode`. Searching for `LaTeX-` showed me that `LaTeX-mode` is an alias for `latex-mode`.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of <kbd>M-:</kbd> `major-mode` is good, and gives you the correct major mode name (i.e. the symbol name for the mode function).

I don't believe there's a standard function to list the symbol names for the current buffer's enabled minor modes, but you can see *all* (loaded) minor mode symbols with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `minor-mode-list`, so it's not hard to verify a name if you find you need to.

The symbol name for a mode's **hook** is literally the mode's symbol name with the suffix `-hook`.

*Minor* modes also have (in addition) an `-on-hook` and `-off-hook`.

The hook variables don't necessarily exist when not in use, but this naming is hard-coded in the standard macros for defining modes (and running their hooks at the appropriate times); and the modes which don't use those macros  invariably follow the same conventions, to ensure consistency.